# LINQ querying different DataSets, based on input parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I've battled this question for quite a while now, and I really want to know if it's possible or not. This is my current code, but I really don't like using a switch case. Is there a way of getting around it?

```
public async Task<RequestOutputModel> SearchById(int id, string category, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    RequestOutputModel query;
    switch (category)
    {
        case "RequestTypeOne":
            query = await this.mapper
                        .ProjectTo<RequestTypeOneOutputModel>(this
                        .Data
                            .RequestTypeOne
                            .Where(e => e.Id == id))
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
            break;
        case "RequestTypeTwo":
            query = await this.mapper
                        .ProjectTo<RequestTypeTwoOutputModel>(this
                            .Data
                            .RequestTypeTwo
                            .Where(e => e.Id == id))
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
            break;
```

Comment: If these output models are quite different I don't see how you can generalize this. BTW why do you use the single method for different datasets?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>` (or `Dictionary<string, Func<CollectionItem, bool>>` for LINQ to Objects) and use it instead of `if/else` or `switch/case`

```
private conditions = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<YourLinqEntityClass, bool>>>() {
    { "Q", /* cond Q */ },
    { "W", /* cond W */ },
    { "E", /* cond E */ },
    // (...)
    { "P", /* cond P */ }
}

IEnumerable<list> function()
{
    if(conditions.ContainsKey(category))
        return db.Entities.Where(conditions(category));
    return db.Entities;
}
```